# How to avoid auto-docking in Windows 7 for my Adobe AIR app?

Tags: air

I just created an Adobe AIR app but I found that it automatically docks to the four edges in Win 7. I don't want this feature in my AIR so I can't just disable it in my system. Is there any settings I can adjust to disable it particularly in my AIR app?

Thanks,

Comment: If I remember correctly, Windows doesn't apply Aero Snap if your app cannot be resized. So you could try to make it impossible to resize the window. Beyond that, I know of no way to do it

Comment: @JoshJanusch Thanks, that's a very interesting suggestion and I'm totally ok with my app non-resizable. I will do some search now.